# How do I access a FormGroup value from a separate component in Angular2?

Tags: angular, typescript

So in my FromComponent I have a FormGroup.
I have another component named ReviewComponent that doesn't have a FormGroup.

I need to access the data in the FromComponent's FormGroup....for example (FromForm.controls.contact.value).

I know how to pass regular variables on to separate components, but whenever I try to access a FormGroup, it just comes up as undefined.

```
    import {
    FormBuilder,
    Validators,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormGroup,
    ControlValueAccessor,
}                               from '@angular/forms';
import {
    Component,
    Input,
    Output,
    OnInit,
    ElementRef,
    Injectable,
    ViewEncapsulation,
    ViewChild,
    OnChanges,
    AfterViewInit
}                               from '@angular/core';


@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'app-wiz-from',
})

@Injectable()
export class WizFromComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges, AfterViewInit {
    public fromForm: FormGroup;

    constructor(
        public fb: FormBuilder, 
    ) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        // Create the Form Group.
        this.fromForm = this.fb.group({
            contact: [this.shipment.shipment[0].addresses[0].contactName, Validators.required],
            email: [this.shipment.shipment[0].addresses[0].email, Validators.pattern(this.email_reg)]
        });
    }


    goNext() {
        console.log('Testing Data: ', this.fromForm);
        var address = new Addresses()
        address.type = 'fromPerson',
        address.contactName = this.fromForm.controls.contact.value,
        address.email = this.fromForm.controls.email.value
        console.log('Clicked Next on From!');
    }
}
```

Then on my outside component:

```
import { WizShipFromComponent } from '../wiz-ship-from/wiz-ship-from.component';

constructor(
        public wizFrom: WizFromComponent
    ) {}

export class WizReview() {
    console.log('From Contact: ', this.wizFrom.fromForm);
}
```

But when I try to call this.wizFrom.fromForm like above, it returns undefined.
Even stranger to me, if I just call the goNext() function from WizFromComponent, the function runs, but the fromForm.controls all come up as undefined.

Any other type of variable returns fine. 
What do I have to do to get the FormGroup data?

Comment: Does the template of ReviewComponent contain the FromComponent?

Comment: Yes. The ReviewComponent template calls <app-wiz-from> to display the FromComponent inside of the Review. The FromComponent has the form on it, and I am trying to "submit" it from a button on the ReviewComponent  that just calls this.wizFrom.goNext(). But that doesn't see the FormGroup for some reason.  address.contactName = this.shipperForm.controls.contact.value gives error "Cannot read property 'controls' of undefined.

Comment: If I run the function goNext() directly from the WizFrom component (this.wizFrom.fromForm) has all of the FormGroup data, but running that same function from the review component will not show data in the formgroup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what you written in your answer on my comment, I would suggest the following solution:
In the class of Review declare the reference to `FromComponent` using `ViewChild`.
This way you'll be able to call `goNext()` along with all the other public attributes and methods defined in `FromComponent`inside Review (you can't just instantiate a variable of `WizFromComponent` inside Review and expect to get the data from the child component, this won't work).

```
import { WizShipFromComponent } from '../wiz-ship-from/wiz-ship-from.component';


  export class WizReview() {

    @ViewChild(FromComponent)
    private wizFrom: FromComponent;

    public callingFromMethodsAndAttributes() {
      console.log('From Contact: ', this.wizFrom.fromForm);
      console.log('Go Next: ', this.wizFrom.goNext());
    }

  }
```

One last thing I noticed, is that you're annotating `FromComponent` with `@Injectbale()`. In angular, you should only declare services as `Injectable` and not components.

Comment: Can you explain @ViewChild? Your answer makes a lot of sense, but from the documentation, I still don't fully understand how ViewChild works. Thank you all very much for the help.

Comment: From angular's documentation:   
"You can use ViewChild to get the first element or the directive matching the selector from the view DOM. If the view DOM changes, and a new child matches the selector, the property will be updated."
Take this as an example:
<parentElement>
  <childElement>
  </childElement>
</parentElement>
If ParentComponent wants to keep track of ChildComponent, we should declare in ParentComponent definition class ViewChild of type ChildComponent. And any change that happens inside ChildComponent will update the reference to ChildComponent created in ParentComponent.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you're trying to inject the WizFromComponent into the ReviewComponent. It doesn't work like this. You can inject services and not components.

Create an injectable service and inject it into both WizFromComponent and ReviewComponent. Then the code in the WizFromComponent should put the object fromForm into this service, and the ReviewComponent should get it from there.

Comment: That makes sense, I guess the real issue I'm having here is calling the function from WizFromComponent from WizReview. Basically, I'm loading the WizFromComponent inside of the ReviewComponent so I can see the data and make changes to it. When I call this.wizFrom.goNext(), the FormGroup shows as empty.

Comment: You can invoke the child's component API from a parent component using the  @ViewChild decorator, but if you're trying to invoke a method on component B from a sibling component A, it's an anti-pattern.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still pretty new at Angular. I am trying to call a function on component "A" from component "B". I can call the function fine, but when called from component "B", FormGroup on form "A" is undefined.